# RPM Custom Error on Exit

Tags: error-handling, rpm

I would like to exit my RPM with a custom error message when certain files are missing during the build process. I can use echo and then call exit -1 but that looks kind of hackish when its printed and the message prints above the actual exit status. I would like to print something like error: That thing you need is missing. Is this possible?

Comment: You can print anything you want but I don't think you can get it to print out any later in the output than it already is. Can you not add those files as BuildRequires? Doing that should cause the build to bail out much earlier I believe.

Comment: I wont go into to much detail but files will vary during each build. It's just an aesthetic thing though. I guess I'll simply have to echo my error before exit -1.

Comment: You could always wrap the `rpmbuild` call in a script that does those checks (assuming they can be lifted out of the build like that).

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but would be an extra layer to worry about. Thanks for the input though!